# mvc タグを model-view-controller タグに付け替えたい

Tags: 討議, 完了, タグ, タグの付け替えの提案

[mvc](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc) というタグがあるのですが、タグ名が略称になってしまっています。

[model-view-controller](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/model-view-controller) タグを新設し、[mvc](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc) をそちらへマージする形でタグの付け替えを行いたいです。

カタカナで [モデルビューコントローラー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%83%a2%e3%83%87%e3%83%ab%e3%83%93%e3%83%a5%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b3%e3%83%b3%e3%83%88%e3%83%ad%e3%83%bc%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bc) タグとすることも考えましたが、日本語版 Wikipedia でも "Model-View-Controller" と書かれておりますし英語のままで通じるかなと考えています: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_Controller

ちなみに英語版では [model-view-controller] がメインタグとして用意された上で別名として [mvc] が用意されており、今回提案しているものと同じ形になっています。

Comment: 反対意見が無いようですので、対応予定とします。一週間程度、追加の意見を待った後に作業いたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

作業を完了しました。

現在、[タグ情報（タグWiki）](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/model-view-controller/info) では「MVC」という語しか使われていませんので、必要であれば編集でタグ名との整合を取って下さい。